# How to read from config.toml in rust?

Tags: rust

I have what I thought should be a simple question. I want the following three things:

1. Have a default value in a config.toml
2. Be able to override that value by passing a config flag
3. Be able to read that value in a program

Ex:

config.toml

```
[env]
FOO="BAR"
```

command line arg

```
 cargo --config FOO="BAZZ"
```

main.rs

```
let a = read_from_env("FOO").unwrap()
```

Comment: Did you have a look at std::env?

Comment: I did. I dumped my std::envs() in a print statement to see whats there, and my config.toml values were not there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have a `.cargo/config.toml` containing

```
[env]
foo="bar"
```

And a `./src/main.rs` containing

```rust
fn main() {
    let foo = env!("foo");
    println!("{}", foo);
}
```

- `cargo run` will print `bar` (from the config)
- `foo=baz cargo run` will print `baz` (from the environment)
- `cargo run --config some/config.toml` can also be used to specify the `config.toml`

---

Note that you get the wrong result if `cargo run` does not trigger a rebuild. You can use `cargo clean` (or even `touch ./src/main.rs`) to force a rebuild.

Comment: That's what I thought. For some reason, that doesn't work for me.

Comment: I get the following error error: environment variable `FOO` not defined at compile time

Comment: The .cargo is on the same file level as the cargo.toml

Comment: `./` is the root of the project in my example. If that's the case for you aswell, I can't reproduce your problem. You could try explicity passing in the config file using 
`cargo run --config ./cargo/config.toml` to see what that yields.

Comment: I passed in the file path and it worked. Thanks!